# How to increase Scrapy crawling speed?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to crawl websites and extract data to a json file, but I've found that for some sites the crawler takes ages to crawl the complete website.

My question is: How can I minimize the time taken to crawl?

Answer (score 4):

Try tuning the `CONCURRENT_ITEMS`, `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`, `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` and other settings.

For full list of settings, see http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html

Comment: Hi @DaniloBargen.. Thanks for the quick response. My question is ideally what should be the values set for CONCURRENT_ITEMS, CONCURRENT_REQUESTS, CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN so that our crawler executes fast? I mean how I will decide what values should be set or do I have to do trial and error kind of thing to see how it works?

Comment: Trial and error. These values are very dependent on the webserver of the site being crawled, as well as your internet connection (obviously). But you can take a look at the default values (see documentation) and start increasing them to observe the effect.

Comment: Hi @DaniloBargen.. I tried setting values for CONCURRENT_ITEMS, CONCURRENT_REQUESTS, CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN in my Spider file. But the Website which I am using to extract data from is quite big and its becoming difficult for me to test the time taken to crawl entire site by trial and error method for these values as i have to wait for quite a time to execute the crawler and then again change the values and test. Is there any other way around for me to try out combination of these values for a particular site to see the outcome fast enough to test. Thanks..

Comment: Limit the number of pages you're crawling to 100 or so.

Comment: @DaniloBargen.. i tried to add limit using Extension "scrapy.contrib.closespider.CloseSpider" and set CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT = 100..but still it takes a lot of time. I also reduced the value to 5  still not working for me. Is the reason because I have set rule : rules = [ 
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), follow=True, callback=('parse_item'))
   ]

Comment: kishan: I'm not sure, you should probably post to the mailing list. But maybe the webserver is simply slow, so it takes a lot of time?

Comment: Ok @DaniloBargen.. thanks for your help.. Will look into it. Meanwhile if you find any answer let me know..