# increase scrapy crawlera crawling speed

Tags: scrapy

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 50
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 50
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = False
DOWNLOAD_DELAY= 0
```

after checking [How to increase Scrapy crawling speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109871/how-to-increase-scrapy-crawling-speed), my scraper is still slow and takes about 25 hours to scrape 12000 pages (Google,Amazon), I use Crawlera, Is there more I can do to increase speed and when `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS =50` does this mean I have 50 thread like request?

Comment: For me, the more you increase the `CONCURRRENT_REQUESTS` the more you take the risk to be ban. Personally I was facing the same problem as you. So I run the same spider several times at one times with tor and polipo proxy, where all my spiders are listening on different circuits and ports. For 6000 urls it takes about 20-30 minutes. If you are interested about it, it gonna be a long answer I can do... so tell me.

Comment: @AvyWam I am very interested, please share

Comment: Have you seen https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000188397-crawlera-best-practices?

Answer (score 1):

#How to run several instances of a spider

Your spider can take some arguments in the terminal as the following: `scrapy crawl spider -a arg=value`.

Let's imagine you want to start 10 instances because I guess you start with 10 urls (quote: input is usually 10 urls). The commands could be like this:

```
scrapy crawl spider -a arg=url1 &
scrapy crawl spider -a arg=url2 &
...
scrapy crawl spider -a arg=url3
```

Where `&` indicates you launch a command after the previous one without waiting the end of this previous one. As far as I know it's the same syntax in Windows or Ubuntu for this particular need.

##Spider source code
To be able to launch as I showed you, the spider can look like this

```
class spiderExample(scrapy.Spiper):
    def __init__(arg): #all args in here are able to be entered in terminal with -a
        self.arg = arg #or self.start_urls = [arg] , because it can answer your problematic
        ... #any instructions you want, to initialize variables you need in the proccess 
            #by calling them with self.correspondingVariable in any method of the spider.
    def parse(self,response):#will start with start_urls
        ... #any instructions you want to in the current parsing method
```

#To avoid to be banned
As far as I read you use Crawlera. Personally I never used this. I never needed to use payable services for it.

##One IP for each spider
The goal here is clear. As I told you in comment I use Tor and Polipo. Tor needs an HTTP proxy like Polipo or Privoxy to run in a scrapy spider correctly. Tor will be tunneled with the HTTP proxy, and at the end the proxy will work with a Tor IP. Where Crawlera can be interesting is Tor's IPs are well known by some websites with a lot of traffic (so a lot of robots going through it too...). These websites can ban Tor's IP because they detected robots behaviors corresponding with the same IP.

Well, I don't know how work Crawlera, so I don't know how you can open several ports and use several IP's with Crawlera. Look at it by yourself. In my case with Polipo I can run several instances tunneled (polipo is listening the tor's corresponding socks port) on several Tor circuits launched by my own. Each Polipo instances has its own listen port. Then for each spider I can run the following

```
scrapy crawl spider -a arg=url1 -s HTTP_PROXY:127.0.0.1:30001 &
scrapy crawl spider -a arg=url2 -s HTTP_PROXY:127.0.0.1:30002 &
...
scrapy crawl spider -a arg=url10 -s HTTP_PROXY:127.0.0.1:30010 &
```

Here, each port will listen with different IP's, so for the website these are different users. Then your spider can be more polite (look at settings options) and your whole project be faster. So no need to go through the roof by setting `300` to `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` or to `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`, it will make the website turn the wheel and generates unnecessary event like  `DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.website.com/page3000> (failed 5 times): 500 Internal Server Error`.

In my personal preferences I like to set different log file for each spider. It avoids to explodes the amount of lines in the terminal, and allows to let me read the events of processes in a more comfortable text file. Easy to write in the command `-s LOG_FILE=thingy1.log`. It will show you easily if some urls where not scraped as you wanted.

##Random user agent.
When I read Crawlera is a smart solution because it uses the right user agent to avoid to be banned... I was surprised because actually you can do it by your own-self like [here](https://pkmishra.github.io/blog/2013/03/18/how-to-run-scrapy-with-TOR-and-multiple-browser-agents-part-1-mac/). The most important aspect when you do it by yourself is to choose popular user-agent to be overlooked among the large number of users of this same agent. You have available lists on some websites. Besides, be careful and take computer user-agent and not other device like mobile because the rendered page, I mean source code, is not necessarily the same and you can lose the information you want to **scrape**.

The main cons of my solution is it consumes your computer resources. So your choice of number of instances will depend on your computer capacities (RAM,CPU...), and router capacities too. Personally I am still using ADSL and as I told you 6000 requests were done in 20-30 minutes... But my solution does not consume more bandwidth than setting a crazy amount on `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can affect your crawler speed. But `CONCURRENT_REQUEST` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` settings. Try setting them to some absurdly hard number like `300` and go from there.

see: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests

Other than that ensure that you have `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED` set to `False` and `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` set to `0`.

Even if scrapy is limited by it's internal behaviour you can always fire up multple instances of your crawler and scale your speed like that. Common atomic approach is to put urls/ids to a `redis` or `rabbitmq` queue and pop->crawl them in mutliple scrapy instances.

Comment: the links are spider generated,I mean that input is usually 10 urls then spider finds the rest of 10k urls based on them. Also you mentioned 300 concurrent Crawlera plan offers up to 50 will this affect process ?

Comment: @Piggydog If crawlera offers only 50 then you're kinda limited by that. This might be your bottle neck - either ditch crawlera in favor of some other solution or upgrade your plan.